# Getting back primitive array after insertion into an ArrayList of primitive arrays in Java

Tags: java

```
List<double[]> x = new ArrayList<double[]>();
x.add(new double[]={1,2,3,4,54,6});
```

elements 1,2,3,4,54,6 are added to x

```
x.get(0) ---> returns 1
```

But doing this, address of array is added? why

```
     List<double[]> x = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    double[] name=new double[5];
    name[0]=1
    name[1]=3;
    name[2]=3;
        .
        . 
        . 
        .
    x.add(name);
    getting x.get(0) ---> returns @as12cd2 (address of the array)
```

Comment: That's nothing special, the array is the only element of the list. What surprises me is that in the first example, apparently some unboxing is done, and then the list contains `double` elements rather than `double[]` as it should. This is straight-up odd, and might lead to errors, as `get(...)` is expected to return `double[]` at compile time but returns `double` at runtime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the `List` is being made up of `double[]` instead of `double`.

Because a `double[]` is an array, you have to specify the position from that array as well. Like so:

```
x.get(0)[0]
```

If you want to be able to just use `x.get()`, your `List` must be made up of `double` primitives. Then you can add the array of `doubles` to the `List` using a separate method (I don't know of one that is built in):

```
List<Double> addArray(List<Double> o, double[] a) {
  for(Double d : a)
    o.add(d);

  return o;
}
```

Hopefully that makes sense. I like using short variable names to make the logic more clear. As long as you know what the variables are, you should be fine.

Comment: List can only store objects, so you will have to use Double instead of double

Comment: That's quite logical, but doesn't explain why the first example works. By this logic, it should have the same result as the second one, since there a `double[]` list is used as well.

Comment: Also, there's no built-in single method for adding an array to an existing list, but it works one-line with `doubleList.addAll(Arrays.asList(doubleArray)`. See @n00begon 's answer below.

Answer (score 57):

If you just want your list to store the doubles instead of arrays of doubles, change what the list is storing

```
List<Double> doubleList = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

Then you can add the array as a list to your array list which will mean the list is storing the values rather than the array. This will give you the behaviour that `get(0)` will give you 1 rather than the array address

```
Double[] doubleArray = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 54.0, 6.0 };
doubleList.addAll(Arrays.asList(doubleArray));
doubleList.get(0); //gives 1.0
```

Comment: Adding of array is possible to simplify:
doubleList.addAll(Arrays.asList(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 54.0, 6.0));

Comment: @sasha_trn I agree, I just spaced it out for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

`double[]` array is object. So, you get address and entire array is added at index 0.

You may use `Arrays.toString(x.get(0))` to get readable array print.

toString() for an array is to print [, followed by a character representing the data type of the array's elements, followed by @ then the memory address.

Comment: The OP doesn't want to print an array. He wonders why the array is added as a single element, rather than being unboxed. Which is, as pointed out above, because the list stores `double[]`. And a way to add the elements of an aray to a list is also shown.

Answer (score 1):

The default `toString()` implementation of any `Object` (including the `double[]`) is the return of the Object address. This is what it is printed by your code.

Comment: That's not what the question is about. Reading the lines between the code, you'll notice that the OP is not surprised about how the array is printed, but rather by that the array is put into the list as one single element, instead of being unboxed. The reason of which the 2 currently topmost answers (by @Jon and @n00begon) explain very well.