# How to copy/add an Array to a List of Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I'm new in the java, and I've been battling in copying a String array to an ArrayList but it does not store the values, instead stores the address of the array.

```
String[] newLine = { "name", "location", "price" };
List<String[]> outList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
outList.add(newLine);

for(String[] rows: outList)
{
    System.out.println(row);
}
```

I get printed

> ["name", "location", "price"]

If i change the value of newHeader it changes as well in the List.

```
newLine[0] = "NEW VALUE";
for(String[] rows : outList)
{
    System.out.println(row);
}
```

Output:

> ["NEW VALUE", "location", "price"];

How do I just add/copy the values of the Array to the ArrayList?

Maybe It isn't clear but I would like to have something like this at the end:

```
outList should contain *n* String Arrays e.g.      

["name", "location", "price"] 
["name2", "location2", "price2"]
["name3", "location3", "price3"]
["name4", "location4", "price4"]
```

Comment: see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12149314/adding-array-to-a-list-in-java

Answer (score 3):

you can simply do this:

```
list.addAll(Arrays.asList(myArray));
```

Comment: He doesn't want to add the individual elements, but the array itself. -.-

Comment: @Clashsoft that doesn't seem to be what he is asking 'add/copy the values of the Array to the ArrayList'

Comment: @Woot4Moo it does not work. It throws an error "type mismatch: cannot convert from List<String> to Collection < ? extends String []>".

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by storing a copy of the array rather than the array itself:

```
String[] newLine = { "name", "location", "price" }
String[] copy = newLine.clone();
outList.add(copy);
```

The `clone()` method will create a copy of the array that has the same elements and size, but is a different reference / address.

If you now change an element of the original array, the copy doesn't change.

```
newLine[0] = "NEW VALUE";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newLine)); // prints [NEW VALUE, location, price]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(copy)); // prints [name, location, price]
```

Comment: but then If I would want to populate my outputList with n Array values then I would have to create n clones?

Comment: Correct - but there is no other way. If you do not copy/clone your array you run into the problems you stated in the question. But don't worry, it's a shallow copy: the actual strings are not copied, so the overhead is not too bad.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out that I can do this:

```
String[] newLine = { "name", "location", "price" };

List<String[]> outList = new ArrayList<String[]>();

outList.add(new String []{newLine[0], newLine[1], newLine[2]});
```

Now if I will change the value of newLine it will not alter the outList.
But I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: `new String []{newLine[0], newLine[1], newLine[2]}` is essentially the same as `newLine.clone()`. I think you should probably accept @Clashsoft's answer...